How to combine two Datasets to create list of nested JSON objects
I am new to Apache Spark (Java) and am trying to create a text file consisting of multiple json objects that represent a combination of these two datasets. The firstToSecondGeneration is very long so I omitted the columns between ch3 and ch99.
Here are the two datasets I'm trying to join:
Dataset<Row> firstToSecondGeneration:
name|ch1|ch2 |ch3   |ch99   
Bob|Joe|James|      |  
Sue|Joe|James|      |  
John|  |     |      |Johnny  

DataSet<Row> secondToThirdGeneration:
chName| gChname  
Joe|   Joe Jr.  
Joe|   Josephine  
James| James Jr.  
James| Jamie  
Johnny| Johnny Jr.  

And here is what I want to return:
Expected result:
    {  
        "name": "Bob",  
        "children": [  
            {  
                "childName": "Joe",  
                "grandChildren":[  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "Joe Jr."  
                    },  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "Josephine"  
                    }  
                ]  
            },  
            {  
                "childName": "James",  
                "grandChildren":[  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "James Jr."  
                    },  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "Jamie"  
                    }  
                ]  
            }  
        ]  
    }  
    {  
        "name": "Sue",  
        "children": [  
            {  
                "childName": "Joe",  
                "grandChildren":[  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "Joe Jr."  
                    },  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "Josephine"  
                    }  
                ]  
            },  
            {  
                "childName": "James",  
                "grandChildren":[  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "James Jr."  
                    },  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "Jamie"  
                    }  
                ]  
            }  
        ]  
    }  
    {  
        "name": "John",  
        "children": [  
            {  
                "childName": "Johnny",  
                "grandChildren":[  
                    {  
                        "grandChildName": "Johnny Jr."  
                    }  
                ]  
            }  
        ]  
    }  

I have a working solution where I simply collect all the chName in a list and do some string concatenation to create the json strings, but I want to avoid doing that as I feel I'm not fully leveraging Spark with my current solution.

Your input and output is lot different.. can you please add actual input & expected output.

I'm not sure what you're requesting. These are the real input and output. The only difference is I omitted the empty columns ch4-ch98 from firstToSecondGeneration.
